# CSS Gradients... opinions?

Tags: css, background, cross-browser, gradient

I've been designing website for a long time just using images for gradients, for small gradients this seems to work fine and not add much loading time, but right now with so much fragmentation with newer CSS (webkit/moz/o/khtml, and not to mention ie 6,7,8,9)

so in order for just one universal gradient theres gonna be a lot of css.

With sites that are going to require a ton of gradients I use Less.js to make it slightly better, but this only goes so far...

I was just wondering at what size does it make more sense to use css gradients over images, if there really is a breaking point.

[ex. a small 5px gradient, it makes more sense to just have a 5px image, but like a 1000px gradient it probably makes more sense to just use css]

Oh and I know there's SVG, I haven't really tried it but does it work well?

Any opinions would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: SVG works well, but there are differences between agents: Chrome does it a lot better than FF. I've combind gradient/opacity with animation ...

Comment: try this: http://xmlsoap.dk/svg/vignette.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using images is that you are much more restricted in what you can do. If you want to use a background gradient and the box is larger than you anticipated, either the gradient stops early or it starts repeating. Both solutions are probably not what you want.

You could check [www.css3please.com](http://www.css3please.com) for examples on how to get the nice effects in css3 (with live sample code). For background gradients you can use the following:

```
.box_gradient {
  background-color: #444444;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* FF3.6 */
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* IE10 */
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#444444', EndColorStr='#999999'); /* IE6–IE9 */
}
```

Comment: Would be great if all browsers supported `linear-gradient` at the same time. :-(

Answer (score 2):

To sum up: you can get support for gradients via a single SVG in **every browser** that supports CSS3 gradients, with bonus points for IE9 support, Opera going back a long time (only recently supported -o- prefixed CSS3 gradients recently), and it removes the issues that crop up due to the differences in the two webkit syntaxes. The two webkit syntaxes aren't just different ordering or combination of words and numbers, they're completely incompatible with each other, and it can be very hard to normalize.

That's if you're using the SVG as an a background image from a file. If you go the extra step to embedding the SVG as a datauri you lose support for Firefox prior to 6. All version of firefox support the "correct" CSS3 gradient syntax though, so it's not too much of a chore in most cases to just use the SVG datauri plus -moz- CSS3.

The main trick is that it takes some screwing around and learning the interactions between SVG internal sizing -> viewport -> CSS background internal sizing/tiling -> and finally modifiers like background-size. This is why, despite it being a catch all, that people avoid using SVG.

The thing I've failed at succeeding at is normalizing between CSS3 repeating gradients with percentage based stops and SVG at the same time (supporting with -moz-). The problem is that no matter what combination of ways to produce the desired result, one or the other requires background-size to be set in such a way that it breaks the other. That's a pretty specific use case.

Here's a horizontal linear gradient:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>stop{stop-color:#f00}</style>
  <linearGradient id="g">
    <stop stop-opacity=".4"/>
    <stop stop-opacity="0" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#g)"/>
</svg>
```

As datauri (spacing and line breaks removed)

```
#base64 {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxzdHlsZT5zdG9we3N0b3AtY29sb3I6I2YwMH08L3N0eWxlPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iZyI+PHN0b3Agc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIuNCIvPjxzdG9wIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMCIgb2Zmc2V0PSIxIi8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2cpIi8+PC9zdmc+);
}
```

And here's that as CSS3

```
#css3 {
                                                   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, 
  from(0,rgba(255,0,0,0)),to(1,rgba(255,0,0,.4))); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
  right, rgba(255,0,0,0),      rgba(255,0,0,.4));  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
  right, rgba(255,0,0,0),      rgba(255,0,0,.4));  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(
  right, rgba(255,0,0,0),      rgba(255,0,0,.4));  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
  right, rgba(255,0,0,0),      rgba(255,0,0,.4));  background-image:  linear-gradient(
  right, rgba(255,0,0,0),      rgba(255,0,0,.4));  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
  startColorstr="#33ff0000", endColorstr="#00ff0000", GradientType=1);
}
```

Here's a repeating diaganal stripes SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="900" height="900">
    <style>
        stop{stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0}
        [b]{stop-opacity:.15}
    </style>
    <linearGradient id="g" x1="1" x2="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset=".25" b=""/>
        <stop offset=".25"/>
        <stop offset=".5"/>
        <stop offset=".5" b=""/>
        <stop offset=".75" b=""/>
        <stop offset=".75"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <rect width="900" height="900" fill="url(#g)"/>
</svg>
```

And the datauri

```
.diag {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-size: 33% auto;
}
```

And the CSS3 for it, which won't hit IE9:

```
background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,
    rgba(255,255,255,.15), rgba(255,255,255,.15) 15%,
    rgba(255,255,255,  0) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,  0) 30%);
background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,
    rgba(255,255,255,.15), rgba(255,255,255,.15) 15%,
    rgba(255,255,255,  0) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,  0) 30%);
background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,
    rgba(255,255,255,.15), rgba(255,255,255,.15) 15%,
    rgba(255,255,255,  0) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,  0) 30%);
background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,
    rgba(255,255,255,.15), rgba(255,255,255,.15) 15%,
    rgba(255,255,255,  0) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,  0) 30%);
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,
    rgba(255,255,255,.15), rgba(255,255,255,.15) 15%,
    rgba(255,255,255,  0) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,  0) 30%);
```

...Or something like that, I've mangled it so many times trying to get the SVG to look the same as the gradient to covert Firefox <6 but can't find a way to get the two rules to coexist (the background sizing) without getting it right that I forgot what I originally had. May just bite the bullet and fallback to pulling it from a file (which works fine) or a minimal JS shim to make firefox load the datauri.

Plus what the old Webkit syntax would be...something that would use background-size and invariably break the new syntax. Have fun getting both Webkit syntaxes to work at the same time for this one without one breaking the other.

The purpose of using a percentage here for me was in using one gradient to support large and small containers with size appropriate stripes, while also auto sizing to either height or width, whichever is more appropriate for the specific element.

There are gotchas here so it's not a walk in the park. There's some random browser bugs that you find if you go down the rabbit hole. Like I had the repeating gradient set up different, specified in SVG's way of defining a repeating gradient. Worked great in IE9 but apparently there's some odd issues in WebKit when embedded as a datauri and percentage width applied across multiple different size elements. Basically it was using one single shared copied of the SVG paint server for multiple elements and causing it to size to the first element opened, and then be half broken and semi-resizing as other stuff opened.

But at the end of the day it's been easier to deal with the SVG issues than the CSS3 gradient issues when targeting the same set of browsers. You have to use SVG to cover IE9 anyway (the ms-filter is trash and will not work with any other CSS3 stuff like border radius, it sucks ass all the way through the parking lot for performance).

Wrote most of this up here: http://bbenvie.com/svggrads

As an addendum, here's a writeup on achieving sprited gradients in SVG (multiple gradients from one svg): http://abouthalf.com/2010/10/25/internet-explorer-9-gradients-with-rounded-corners/.

Answer (score 1):

My current approach is to use the CSS3 gradient (`webkit-`, `moz-`, etc.) and provide the old background image as a fallback. The size of the image doesn't tend to be an issue given current bandwidths - even a 200px gradient only takes about 200 bytes. The majority of the overhead is from latency from multiple requests for the images - which would be eliminate using CSS.

The main gains from using CSS is that it would reduce the number of requests. The more images that you use on a page the greater the gains.

Answer (score 1):

The code I use for all browser gradients:

```css
background: #0A284B;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0A284B), to(#135887));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0A284B, #135887);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0A284B', endColorstr='#135887');
zoom: 1;
```

You will need to specify a height or `zoom: 1` to apply `hasLayout` to the element for this to work in IE.

---

**Update:**

Here is a LESS Mixin (CSS) version for all you LESS users out there:

```css
.gradient(@start, @end) {
    background: mix(@start, @end, 50%);
    filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr="@start~", EndColorStr="@end~")";
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@start), to(@end));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @start, @end);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    background: linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    zoom: 1;
}
```